# How to update selected item when bottom navigation switch to Navigation Rail

Tags: java, android, bottomnavigationview, landscape-portrait, multiscreen

I have a **Bottom-Navigation** in portrait Mode and a **Navigation-Rail-View** in landscape mode.

How can I update the selected item when the device is rotated?

I tried it with `savedInstanceState`, with override the`onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`.

But because I use `savedInstanceState` for other things too, overide the two above methods cause crash.

Comment: I find out it's not about overide, Where ever I put navigationRailView.setSelectedItemId(), after that I get: savedInstanceState = null

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I found a solution.

But before that, I should mention that a better title for this question could be: **How to share selection item between the BottomNavigation and NavigationRail.**

Ok, solution:

Just replace `setSelectedItemId` with `getMenu().getItem(itemIndex).setChecked(true)`

Example:

Use:

```
bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(indexOfItem2).setChecked(true);
```

Instead of:

```
bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.item2);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
navigationRailView.setSelected(false);
```